# Eris Solidity Tutorial: How to set the bank?

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, eris-industries

In the [Eris Solidity tutorial](https://docs.erisindustries.com/tutorials/solidity/solidity-1/), a system of a `Bank` and a `FundManager` contract are developed. In the fund manager constructor

```
contract Bank {
    [Bank contract details]

    function setOwner(address newOwner) returns (bool res) {
        if (owner != 0x0 && msg.sender != owner){
            return false;
        }
        owner = newOwner;
        return true;
    }
}

contract FundManager {

    address bank;

    // Constructor
    function FundManager(){
        owner = msg.sender;
        bank = new Bank();
        Bank(bank).setOwner(address(this));
    }
}
```

one sets a reference to a `Bank`.
When I deploy the contract and mine it in a private net and then check for the `bank` reference of the `FundManager`, no reference is found (so I can't deposit, because depositing requires a bank to be set).

Here's how I deploy:

```
var fm_arg = "fm";
var fm = contract_fm.new(fm_arg,
                    {
                         from: eth.accounts[0],
                         data: compiled_fm.FundManager.code,
                         gas: 1000000
                    }, callback);
```

I would think, I should now be able to call the `bank` variable:

```
> fm.bank
undefined
```

Why is the bank not set when I construct the `FundManager`?

Answer (score 1):

You declare bank in **FundManager** as an Ethereum address:

```
address bank;
```

not an instance of the contract **Bank**:

```
Bank bank;
```

Comment: Ok, but then should not `fm.bank` return an address?

Comment: If it were initialized yes, but currently it's not.

Comment: Thats my point: Why is it not initialized? Its in the constructor which is called when I deploy the contract! Do I need to separately deploy the bank contract and create a bank instance?

Comment: Bank is of two different types in your code 1) an Ethereum address and 2) an instance of the contract Bank. Replace bank (the address) with a different name (bankAddr) in the FundManager contract.

Comment: I was starting to think something like that... but then to me thats kind of bad practice to have a variable with the same name be totally different things.

Comment: They both have the same scope and different types (the bank as an Etehreum address is visible inside the method). What is the constructor of Bank? It's wrong to instantiate with a default constructor (no arguments) and then to call the constructor again with the bank argument as done on the second line.

Comment: Its how its done in the tutorial. If you deployed these two contracts, can you show your JavaScript for that?

Comment: What happens when you run them in the solidity browser here: https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/ ? I'm asking because I don't have a clear image of your setup.

Comment: Deployment code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f5270d62467108fca5686d00925ed29a

Comment: The code from the first link does not compile. A lot of undefined variables. https://ethereum.github.io/browser-solidity/#version=soljson-latest.js

Comment: Corrected source: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/49f92686f08174f0b07874bf9c8d37e7

Comment: You still have to generate the one-line source code first.